# C# Object Hierarchy

Tags: c#, object

I have a List of Cells and each List has a List of Stations.

Sometimes I need to get the Parent Cell of a Station.

How would I implement this hierarchy?

- Should I keep the Parent Cell as an Property in the Station Object?
- Should I Keep only the Parent Cell Id in the Station Object?
- Do something differnt?

Comment: Can you also show some example code for each of solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you, I would create two classes:

```
public class Cell {
 ...
  public List<Station> Stations {
    get {...}
  }

  protected Station AddStation() {
     Station result = new Station(this);
     Stations.Add(result);
     return result;
  }
}

public class Station {
  public Station(Cell cell) {
    this.cell = cell;
  }
  Cell cell;
  public Cell Cell {get {return cell;}}
}
```

Having this structure, you can always access the Cell from the Station object.

Comment: I'd also add a `CreateStation`-method to the `Cell`-class to handle the "add to Stations" and "set parent" stuff.

Comment: @Matten, I've added this method :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to navigate back from `Station` to `Cell`, you need the `Station` object to have a `ParentCell` (or `Cell`) property that is set to its parent cell.

Comment: This is one of the alternatives the OP is asking about and thus does not answer the question...

Comment: @Stefan - Yes, it is. This is the alternative I suggest the OP uses, over any other option.

Comment: @Stefan - How is this not answering the question? The OP is asking how to do this, listing some options. I am simply saying one of the options the OP listed is the right one.

Comment: Okey, you're answering the question but are not explaining why to choose this solution. You just could've said: "go for solution 1".

Answer (score 1):

If you want a different answer, there is a way you can implement the hierarchy without actual composition. Create a station object where each method accepts Cell as a parameter, for example:

```
public void DoStuff(whatever x, Cell parent)
{

}
```

Each station will be evaluated in the context of its parent cell, but you can use the same `Station` object to represent different stations in the hierarchy.

This solution is provided for the sake of variety. In most cases, the way to go is composition, as suggested above. Also, I think you should use the Cell itself, rather than an Id to it.